# How can I get tweet ID just posted from my website?

Tags: javascript, php, twitter, twitter-oauth

I can't find anywhere how can I get the tweet's ID after it's being posted from my website (button)

1. is there a non-deprecated way?
2. is there any way? php? js?
3. do I have to create twitter app?
4. is it possible through any of new (1.1) twitter apis

I want to store the ID so I can monitor the favs and retweets later

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are using the Twitter API? When you do a `POST` to `https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/update.json`, the response will contain the tweet id as `id`

This is the documentation
https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/post/statuses/update

Comment: I will check this tomorrow thanks for the quick reply